# Python subprocess used to call another Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have several data folders containing a script `ExportScriptGen.py`, and I want a script that can traverse the directory structure and run `ExportScriptGen.py` in each folder where it is found.  This is what I have so far:

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import subprocess

script = "ExportScriptGen.py"

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    top = sys.argv[1]
else:
    top = os.path.realpath(".")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    if (script in files):
        subprocess.call(os.path.join(root,script), shell=True)
```

`ExportScriptGen.py` generates scripts in another folder (and is tested).  When I test my main script on a small scale (i.e. one folder with `ExportScriptGen.py` and no subdirectories) everything works fine.  However, when I run it on my full-scale problem (which has a large number of directories/subdirectories), no output is produced by `ExportScriptGen.py`.  Why would this be?  I'm running Python 3.2 on Windows 7.

Here's `ExportScriptGen.py`:

```
import sys
import os.path
import os

### Declarations ###

script_check_dir = # directory to place scripts in
layout_name = # parameter to write into top of script
template_name = # template for script
out_script_tail = # string to add at end of output script file

### Code ###

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    folder = sys.argv[1]
else:
    folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

data_files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(folder))
data_files = [f for f in data_files if ("." in f) and os.path.splitext(f)[1][1].isdigit()]

for dfile in data_files:
    out_script_name = os.path.join(script_check_dir, dfile+out_script_tail)
    out_script = open(out_script_name, 'w')

    out_script.write("folder = \"{}\\\"\n".format(folder))
    out_script.write("layout = folder + \"{}\"\n".format(layout_name))
    out_script.write("dataFile = folder + \"{}\"\n".format(dfile))

    template = open(os.path.join(folder, template_name), 'r')
    for line in template:
        out_script.write(line)

    out_script.close()
```

Comment: 'No output'? What does that mean? An exception? It hangs? It quits? It would also be best to give us an example situation with expected output and what you actually get, which we can run and test.

Comment: Also note when working with files you should always use the `with` statement - it will stop you forgetting to close files (as you have done here with `template`) and also ensure they are closed correctly on exceptions. Not to mention it's more readable.

Comment: @Lattyware, 'no output' means it runs, stops normally, and does not produce any output (i.e. there are no scripts in folder `script_check_dir`).

Comment: Have you put in ``print()``s to see what gets run?

Comment: @Lattyware, yes, `ExportScriptGen.py` gets run in each subdirectory, but produces no output.

Comment: So you have one of these `ExportScriptGen.py` in every subdirectory?

Comment: @Keith, that is correct.

Comment: Hm, seems to me to be an overly complicated system.

Comment: Note also that when I run each `ExportScriptGen.py` individually they work as expected.